# Data Validation based off multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Unable to compile all formulas in single cell to validate the data

Reviewed other post's with similar request but I am still unable to figure out what I am doing wrong trying to string these together

Unique Entry's
`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$3000, A2)<=1`

15 Character Max
`=A2>15`

Does not start with a space
`=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)=" "),FALSE,TRUE)`

No Punctuation
`=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")))`

Attempted to string these together using `=OR` but it does not seem to work. Here is what I tried.

`=OR(AND(A2>15),AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$3000,A2)<=1),AND(IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)=" "),FALSE,TRUE)),AND(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")))))`

Another thing I don't understand and may be my issue is that I need this to check `A2:A3000` my formulas do not account for that except for the unique entries but will data validation take that into account or will the formula need to look at all cells? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: With Data validation the formula cannot be greater than 225 characters.  You would also apply the data validation to the whole range(outside the countif) but refer only to the upper left cell with relative reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only use AND:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))),LEFT(A2,1)<>" ",LEN(A2)<=15,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$3000, A2)<=1)
```

Apply it to the whole range but refer to the upper left cell relatively.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much

Comment: @quigleyvision please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Hi Scott, I though this was working but it looks like since the values are TRUE it is actually not allowing input. When they are false is when you are able to apply data to the cell. Any thoughts?

Comment: In a new sheet put the formula in B2 and test inputs on A2.  Use the Evaluate Formula function and see which is triggering incorrectly.